# probability of winning in tennis match

Tags: probability

The probability of **A** winning when **A** and **B** play tennis is $2$ to $1$.

Assume **A** and **B** play $2$ matches.

What is the probability of **A** winning at least $1$ match?

Comment: What is the probability A loses the first match? What is the probability A loses both matches?

Comment: I think if the probability of A loses is none

Comment: You say "the probability [...] is 2 to 1."  This is incorrect.  A probability is a number in between 0 and 1, inclusive.  Perhaps you mean "the odds"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(A wins)=$\frac23$,P(B wins)=$\frac13$.

There are $4$ outcomes: AA, AB, BA, BB, with probabilities $\frac49,\frac29,\frac29,\frac19$ respectively.

P(A wins at least one match)=P(AA)+P(AB)+P(BA)=$\frac89$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of $A$ winning the first match is $2/3$, and the probability of $B$ winning the first match is $1/3$. Same for the second match.

So $P(\text{A wins at least 1 match})=1-P(\text{B wins both matches})=1-(1/3)\cdot(1/3)=8/9.$